# How to get volume level from the command line?

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, scripting, volume

I have a text status bar on a tiling window manager and I am using tcl to feed information to it. At the moment I need a command line that output the volume level 0% to 100%. I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: Looks like you should be able to do it by parsing `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state`.

Comment: Note: in the future, saying you're using Arch isn't really relevant. What actually matters is what sound subsystem you're using, e.g. ALSA, OSS or PulseAudio.

Comment: Instead of adding "closed" to your title, you should just answer your own question and leave it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A one-liner to parse `amixer`'s output for volume in a status bar:

```
awk -F"[][]" '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master)
```

**Edit:**
As of November 2020, the updated amixer for Arch Linux is 1.2.4 which has no 'dB' in the output. So, the command should replaced by:

```
awk -F"[][]" '/Left:/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master)
```

Comment: what does `[][]` mean?

Comment: @approximatenumber It sets the field separator as either `]` or `[`.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know you could have a regex for the `F`

Comment: How would you store this command in a variable ?

Comment: @mike23 `vol=$(awk '/%/ {gsub(/[\[\]]/,""); print $4}' <(amixer sget Master))`

Comment: `amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0`. apparently I have to add `-c 1` to the amixer command, but how can an agnostic one-liner know this?

Comment: also, it would be better to parse the "absolute" (non-percent) volume, as setting by percent seems to have an off by one error for one values (perhaps due to rounding?) so if you save and then restore volume from this command you will make the volume louder.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `amixer` to do this.

#### Examples

```
$ amixer get Master
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [off]
```

You can also change it and mute it like so:

*set volume 75%*

```
$ amixer set Master 75%
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 49152 [75%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 49152 [75%] [on]
```

*mute/unmute*

```
$ amixer set Master toggle
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
```

You can quiet the output if you don't want to see any of it with the `--quiet` switch.

```
$ amixer --quiet set Master 75%
$
```

Answer (score 13):

**Right**

```
amixer sget Master | grep 'Right:' | awk -F'[][]' '{ print $2 }'
85%
```

**Left**

```
amixer sget Master | grep 'Left:' | awk -F'[][]' '{ print $2 }'
85%
```

**Sound server**

If you are not using pulseaudio as default you can specify to `amixer` what server to use with `-D pulse`

```
amixer -D pulse sget Master | grep 'Left:' | awk -F'[][]' '{ print $2 }'
85%
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me... Master for some reason doesn't have "Left" and "Right" despite other channels such as "Speaker" having it.

Answer (score 1):

Based off some of the answers already here, but managed to get avoided using both `awk` and `grep` in the same command (because that would be bloat).

`amixer -D pulse get Master | awk -F 'Left:|[][]' 'BEGIN {RS=""}{ print $3 }'`

**Explanation:**

`amixer -D pulse get Master ...`

Pretty self-explanatory; just lists stuff about our Master control (`-D pulse` because I'm using pulse). For me, it prints:

```
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 52428 [80%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 52428 [80%] [on]
```

`... awk -F 'Left:|[][]' ...`

Uses regex to define field separator, which can be `Left:` or either `][`.

`... { print $3 }'`

Now we print out the 3rd column. Works out that since we separate on `Left:` as well, that the value of `$3` for the right speaker will be blank

`... 'BEGIN {RS=""}...`

Now we're printing only `80%` plus a bunch of newlines. For the script I was writing, I didn't want these, so I removed most of them with `{RS=""}`, and then got rid of a final one at the start by adding in the `BEGIN`

Answer (score 0):

One Solution i have is with using echo(could not find it anywhere so i would love to know if this is not the best way to do),

```
echo "${$(echo "${$(amixer get Master | grep Left:)#*\[}")%%\]*}"
```

i just let Echo delete both the beginning till the first '[' and from the end till the last ']'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me. YMMV.

```
$ amixer get Master | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}%'
51%
$
```